# Connection to sql server in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have my `data access layer` developed for my `wcf` and `win forms` applications. I just started `Xamarin forms` application and want to connect to `sql server` using my current `data access layer`. Nevertheless i got an issue when trying to `connection.Open()` and getting following error. Is there any way to do that?

```
System.Net.Security.Native assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)\n  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+NetSecurityNative.ImportPrincipalName(Interop/NetSecurityNative/Status&,string,int,Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle&)\n  at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle.CreatePrincipal (System.String name) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/Microsoft/Win32/SafeHandles/GssSafeHandles.cs:39 \n  at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteNegoContext..ctor (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.String targetName) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/Unix/SafeDeleteNegoContext.cs:46 \n  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.EstablishSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& context, System.String targetName, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal inFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer inputBuffer, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& outFlags) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/NegotiateStreamPal.Unix.cs:166 \n  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.InitializeSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeCredentials credentialsHandle, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& securityContext, System.String spn, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer[] inSecurityBufferArray, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outSecurityBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& contextFlags) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/NegotiateStreamPal.Unix.cs:240 \n  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.GenSspiClientContext (System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SspiClientContextStatus sspiClientContextStatus, System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.Byte[] serverName) [0x0006b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SNIProxy.cs:113 \n  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.GenerateSspiClientContext (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength, System.Byte[] _sniSpnBuffer) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObjectManaged.cs:240 \n  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.SNISSPIData (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:6488 \nSystem.Net.Security.Native assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)\n  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+NetSecurityNative.ImportPrincipalName(Interop/NetSecurityNative/Status&,string,int,Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle&)\n  at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle.CreatePrincipal (System.String name) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/Microsoft/Win32/SafeHandles/GssSafeHandles.cs:39 \n  at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteNegoContext..ctor (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.String targetName) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/Unix/SafeDeleteNegoContext.cs:46 \n  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.EstablishSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& context, System.String targetName, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal inFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer inputBuffer, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& outFlags) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/NegotiateStreamPal.Unix.cs:166 \n  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.InitializeSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeCredentials credentialsHandle, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& securityContext, System.String spn, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer[] inSecurityBufferArray, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outSecurityBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& contextFlags) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/NegotiateStreamPal.Unix.cs:240 \n  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.GenSspiClientContext (System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SspiClientContextStatus sspiClientContextStatus, System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.Byte[] serverName) [0x0006b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SNIProxy.cs:113 \n  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.GenerateSspiClientContext (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength, System.Byte[] _sniSpnBuffer) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObjectManaged.cs:240 \n  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.SNISSPIData (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:6488
```

Comment: You usually don't do any of this, your create a remote Web resource like rest service and communicate with that. Anything else will result in a redesign sooner or later

Comment: @TheGeneralSo If i understood well you propose to create extra layer and install on server for the xamarin application? WCF or something i suppose to exchange data through this service? If that's correct that means i would need to make extra WCF project or something. Is it really only this way of proper implementation? I really thought i could use my existing data layer.

Comment: It's the recommended approach, and it wouldn't be wcf. There are many reasons why you do this, especially if you are going to make this public facing.

Comment: @TheGeneral Why not WCF and what you suggest?

Comment: Wfc is dying a slow painful death. Just any regular web resource would work well. You can spin them up in. Net core with ease these days. Wcf proxy generation is very lacking from xamarin

Comment: @The General net Core oraz net? Woould net standard 2.0 work with it and what exactly type of project you suggest to choose instead of wcf?

Comment: @Arie Hi, there is a helpful siscussion for reference. Have a look at here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44392/connect-mobile-application-to-sql-server

Comment: @Junior Jiang i wilk to with asi.net Core api

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment to answer yet (not enough reputation), but can you make sure your code is .NET Standard (preferably 2.0 compliant) if using it with Xamarin as a portable class library...Xamarin can't use just any .NET dll unfortunately...also, since I suspect that this might not be (the only) an issue for you could you give more info on the structure of your solution, maybe it's an issue with an assembly not being referenced and being linked out of the final build (i.e. could you make sure it's not working in both Debug as well as Release mode - if you've not modified the Build settings - or just make sure the linker is not going through your code when trying to reduce the final build package size).

Comment: The dal belongs to NET Standard. Ufortunetly i don;t think you right. It looks more like architecture diffrence and external service like WCF has to be used to communication between xamarind android app and sql server. That's my thoughts so far. Regards.